# Plotly Object displays as blank in DataBricks

Tags: python, plotly, databricks

I have a plotly object that should be showing up properly but for some reason it only shows up blank in DataBricks. The object type is:

```
plotly.graph_objs._figure.Figure
```

I have tried the following to display the figure:

```
fig.show()
display(fig)
displayHTML(fig.to_html())
```

All possible solutions I can think of result in the same thing. Thanks!
Btw... Using Plotly Version 4.9

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `plot` method from `plotly.offline`. This following is from [DataBricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/plotly.html), but Jupyter notebooks have a similar issue where a Plotly graph_object Figure won't render unless you use `plotly.offline`.

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Instead of simply calling plot(...), store your plot as a variable and pass it to displayHTML().
# Make sure to specify output_type='div' as a keyword argument.
# (Note that if you call displayHTML() multiple times in the same cell, only the last will take effect.)

p = plot(
  [ ## define your go.Figure here ##

  ],
  output_type='div'
)

displayHTML(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that you can similarly use the `plot` method from `plotly.offline` to display `plotly.express` plots.

This saves a lot of code for simple plots where `graph_objects` are overkill!

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.express as px

p = plot(
    px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]),
    output_type='div'
    )

displayHTML(p)
```